Ubuntu 24.04 LTS booting GUI missing
I was trying in install Ubuntu 24.04 desktop. When the installation was completed, while trying to reboot it was not able to boot to the desktop environment. The boot process stops at this TTY screen.


Your details don't seem correct; you mention install and 22.04; what Ubuntu 24.04 LTS did you install? and why mention 22.04?  Your picture shows a non-24.04 LTS kernel (HWE for 22.04 or the kernel from Ubuntu 23.10). If you installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, what 24.04 did you install?  Server? Desktop? or something else.

Its desktop version in a normal pc. I was updating from 22.04.

Run sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop and reboot.

My pc is under proxy settings. Installation shows proxy not found. Any idea how to solve it?

Can you connect to internet via USB tethering from your phone (which requires no proxy) and run the command again?

I had the same problem of booting to a black screen (CLI). I tried all the solutions posted here and elsewhere and  none worked. I suppose there is a bug somewhere. I switched to Kubuntu and did not experienced the same problem. It was smooth all the way.
